# community detection in directed weighted graph in python

Tags: python, networking, graph, detection

I am looking for a community detection method for directed, weighted graph in python. so far i tried to use these 2 methods but they only work for undirected, unweighted graph.

```
# 1 
c= list(greedy_modularity_communities(usg))
c

# 2
communities_generator = community.girvan_newman(usg)
top_level_communities = next(communities_generator)
next_level_communities = next(communities_generator)
sorted(map(sorted, next_level_communities))
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?